# better way to handle many try except

Tags: python, string, datetime

I'm wondering whats the best way to change the format of a datetime string.

I have a string `time` which represents a datetime object in one of several formats. I want to change it to a specific one. Right now my code looks something like:

```
try:
    record['time'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
except:
    pass
try:
    record['time'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss').strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
except:
    pass
```

And so on.

Is there a better, smarter way to go about this?

Comment: Use the [`dateparser`](https://pypi.org/project/dateparser/) library. Works like a charm for just about any date/datetime you can throw at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd convert to a datetime object from whatever format, then put it in the format you want.  the `dateutil` package has an excellent parser.

````
from dateutil.parser import parse

try:
    as_date = parse(time)
except ValueError:
    # got something unparsable -- figure out how to handle it.

my_formatted_string = as_date.strftime(....)
```
````